# App uploading error in play store

Tags: android, html

`Apk` upload failed and shows this [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8Hc6.png). What can be the issue?

Comment: This happens, because you're using different android store key when building your release apk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't upload updated APK to Google Play due to different certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288234/cant-upload-updated-apk-to-google-play-due-to-different-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

The first time you released that app you had to create a new **Key Store** used to sign it. For any future update you need to sign the app with that same generated Key otherwise Google Play will recognize it as a new one.

You can read from the official Google Docs  [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#release-mode)  on how to sign your Release Build