# Adding ads in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I'm new to Android development and want to know about adding ads in Android app. I researched through various [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#top_of_page) and Android Developers links and finally added the code(s).

**ActivityMain.XML:**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**AndroidManifest.XML:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.package.name">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**App-level gradle:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.ID"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Project-level build.gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Strings.XML:**

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">AppID from AdMob</string>
```

**MainActivity.JAVA:**

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-APPID from ADMob");

AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Is there something which I'm missing? Will I be able to see ads when I publish it as an update to the already published app in Play Store? Also, how will Admob pay me?

There're no errors after running the app.

Thanks,
Kvaibhav01.

***Update:*** I tried to publish the app-release.apk file in the Developer Console and it says:

> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to
>   your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate.

How to fix this?

Comment: your problem is because you use different key to sign the apk. Not because of the admob.

Comment: Okay @ישואוהבאותך. But how to correct the key?

Comment: please read here https://guides.codepath.com/android/Publishing-to-the-Play-Store

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך that didn't gave solution! My app is suffering from _same certificate_ error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate.
>   How to fix this?

I searched [other StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version) and got to know that the answer for above query is only one. That is, **the APK-release file must be signed with the same private key or what you call a KeyStore.** (Java KeyStore to be more specific.)

The mistake I committed was that I accidentally deleted the original KeyStore file. Now if I upload the updated APK with a new KeyStore, Google Developer Console won't recognize it as an update to the already existing app. Instead it assumes that you're uploading a fresh app's APK. That's why you get the above error. Even updating `versionCode` the error persists.

You can read the solution in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26296942/3647180