# SHA-1 key not supporting while uploading release APK to Play store

Tags: android, android-studio

I have developed an application few months ago by Android Studio and the operating system was windows and i did upload that application in play store that time. Now i have changed my operating system from windows to Ubuntu. Now when i am going to upload an update of that application, it's showing SHA-1 key is not matching. Now how can i replace my old SHA-1 key by new SHA-1 key for the application ? Help needed . [upload error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhi3C.png)

Comment: you need to sign your new application with the same keystore used for the old version!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't upload updated APK to Google Play due to different certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288234/cant-upload-updated-apk-to-google-play-due-to-different-certificate)

Comment: Actually its an update  of the older version of application and the "keypassword" is same as before. @Pfennigbaum

Comment: Did you in any case enabled the `Google Play App Signing`? If so, you need to make sure both the upload key (your key) and the app signing key (their key) are in the `Play Console`. Read here: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#google-play-app-signing

Comment: you **must** use your old keystore **file** (except if you did enable Google Play App Signing like @HedShafran mentioned), just the same "keypassword" will not be enough

Comment: well,suppose in case if i found the old sha-1 key then how i will replace it with my new sha-1 key ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything .

**Google** says it clearly that the application is **identified** by the keys used to sign it.

Consequently **if you've lost the keys**, you need to **create a new** application.

Comment: is there any sort of option to replace or restore the SHA-1 key?

Comment: @MohammadHelalUddin as i said you can't **do anything** you must keep your keys in safe place

Comment: well, suppose in case if I find the old sha-1 key then how I will replace it with my new sha-1 key? @Sam Nikzad