# SHA1 is not match with uploaded apk in google play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have an issue while uploading `apk` file in google play console. I recently upgraded my OS to windows 10 and installed android studio and copied all the android projects from previous version. now I am trying to upload the `apk` with same `keystone.jks,` but google play console not allowing me to upload the `apk` saying

> Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again: SHA1: BF:A8:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

How change in the sha1 fingerprint in android studio or in google play store to match it. I don't know the correct process.

Comment: Your `keystone.jks` file is the wrong one. Choose the correct one.'

Comment: rahul i have only one keystone file with me and i am using the same for all projects

Comment: Ok. Are you sure that password is also correct?

Comment: yes password is also correct

Comment: try on some other pc

Comment: @AseshaGeorge did you check signing report file for SHA1 fingerprint?

Comment: yes both sha1 fingerprint are diffrent

Comment: Try changing it.

Comment: how to change it please help me

Comment: check this one hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288234/cant-upload-updated-apk-to-google-play-due-to-different-certificate

Comment: thank you for your replay i found the that i am using same keystore.jks file but certificate is different but how to add this certificate to my app

Comment: Hi. Did you recently enroll in Play Signing? Did you opt for having an upload key different from your app signing key?

Comment: i enrolled long back i did not opt for any thing. its showing i have to upload with same key on every update

Comment: there is an alternative way. we can sent new upload key to google customer care. they will replace the old key with new one. using this link https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs

Comment: @AseshaGeorge did it solve your issue?

Comment: yes my issue is solved. but its not a quick process it will take around 1 week of time to take changes based on the customer care and your response of email.